# Sequence range increased by current absolute number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have some natural numbers that starts from zero, each number could be represented by a simplified number in a small scale. This scale is something like that:

> 0 → 0
>   1 → 1
>   2 → 2
>   3 → 2
>   4 → 3
>   5 → 3
>   6 → 3
>   7 → 4
>   8 → 4
>   9 → 4
>   10 → 4

You can note that from 0 to 2 are represented by itself. Starting by 3, it keeps represented by 2, because the range of 2 is occupy two numbers on sequence. The numbers 4, 5, 6 are part of 3, because the three occupy three number on sequence.

In my case, I could reproduce that inversely, I could translate it from small to big.

> $ f(x) = f(x - 1) + x $

Or then:

> $ 0.5 * x ( x + 1 ) $

But what I need do the reverse of that. If I input on `f(x)` the 7, for instance, it should return 4, if I input 15 it should return 5, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

$$f(n) = 
\left\lfloor{
\frac
{\left\lceil{
\sqrt{8n+1}\,\,
}\right\rceil}
{2}
}\right\rfloor$$

satisfies the specified conditions.

Comment: Math is perfect! Thanks a lot! I just not found how I can get the reverse of my version "mathematically", but I still guess that it is possible. I'm pretty rusty.